# random ads with each call on android

Tags: android, ads

Is it possible to program a theme for a call screen ID that contains a box where random ads can be placed
So that when each call coming, a new ad appears , also a new notification appears.
Is this acceptable and legal in Google Play?

Comment: yes. your problem will be to convince people to use it though.

Comment: @VitaliPom , thanks, I hope not to be rejected by Google, because it will be a lot of time and effort.

Comment: @VitaliPom , What is the guaranteed way to ask google play about that ?

Comment: There is a family program for apps that says that your app is for families and GP gives you a sticker on the store, but there's no restriction on irritating ads as soon as they belong to google's plan.

Comment: wrote it as an answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. your problem will be to convince people to use it though. There is a family program for apps that says that your app is for families and GP gives you a sticker on the store, but there's no restriction on irritating ads as soon as they belong to google's plan.